# GLMM with categorical factor predictors (vegetation type, including road) and continuous factor (distance to road), how to interpret the result?

Tags: r, effects, glmmtmb, glmm, ggeffects

I am doing habitat suitability analysis, and in the predictors, I have categorical factors, continuous factors and their interactions. In the categorical factor (vegetation type), I have one of the categories: **ROAD** (other categories are sth like grassland, water, forest etc.) and the continuous factor is **the distance to the road**. I have also calculated their interaction (which is the only one that make ecological sense).

Now, I have my result and plot from ggeffect (or the effects::Effect). I have this plot for the vegetation type: road. I do not know how to interpret it (like: they choose the water which is far away from the building, sth like this). I do not understand if it makes any sense if the plot shows that the toad would occur when it is around 75m away from the road under the road type of habitat.

The result figure is in the hyperlink below. **AND THE 9 IN THE FIG MEANS ROAD IN HABITAT TYPE.**

[The y-axis is the probability of occurrence (from 0 to 1), and the x-axis is the distance to the nearest road](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kdleZ.png)

Thanks to everyone in advance.

So basically what I want to know is that if it is part of the result, what does it mean? Does it make mathematical sense? Does it make ecological sense? If it does not make sense, is there anything I did wrong with the model? Should I just drop **the distance to road * habitat type**?